# I would like to add many images horizontally in html using CSS

Tags: html, css

```
#one{
border:2px solid black;
border-radius:10px;
background-color:yellow;
padding-top:20px;
padding-left:20px;
padding-bottom:20px;
padding-right:20px;
height:180px;
width:62%;
margin:auto;
}
.im1{
height:180px;
width:200px;
}

<div id="one">
 <img src="inspirational1.jpg" alt="picture1" class="im1"/>
 <img src="inspirational2.jpg" alt="picture2" class="im1"/>
 <img src="inspirational3.jpg" alt="picture3" class="im1"/>
 <img src="inspirational4.jpg" alt="picture4" class="im1"/>
<img src="inspirational5.jpg" alt="picture5" class="im1"/>
 </div>
```

The code above woks perfectly when I'm working im my desktop, but as soon as I open in my laptop all the images are all over the place. I would like to fit them in the div making sure they don't go everywhere if open the website in a new browser, or scree. Any advice is more than welcome please

Comment: Are you using different browsers on your laptop and PC?

Comment: not, they are the same browser

Comment: The browser is irrelevant.

Comment: It looks like they move out of the div because they are too big.  I think you'll need to dynamically adjust the size of the images because  there is no way they will all fit in the div if the screen is not wide enough.  See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CQJ5u/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right you can use float instruction for your images
in css add this line:

```
#one img { float:left; }
```

where #one is the the container div

or using class on the images:
im1 {float:left;}

and after your container add a div with class .clear where clear {clear:both;}

Answer (score 0):

Since your saying just for css.. you can't do it dynamically like if the number of images change..

However with just css and a fixed amount of images, like the 5 you showed in your question, you can just use percentages instead , like this

```
.im1 {
    width: 19%;
}
```

Because 100% width of parent / 5 images = 20% , but sometimes you want to set a little lower to make sure some browsers don't render it incorrectly, so they all fit on the same line.

Also, since your using an id #one for the parent, you might need to use

```
#one .im1 {
   width: 19%;
}
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/LYL2S/1/

```
#one{
border:2px solid black;
border-radius:10px;
background-color:yellow;
padding:20px;

margin:auto;
    width:620px;
}
.im1{
height:180px;
width:200px;
}
```